# config ssl in tcp via spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have configured a server - clinet messaging system on tcp via spring integration, the Main problem now is this configuration for enabling SSL leads to some strange errors for me

```
 <bean id="sslContextSupport"
      class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport">
    <constructor-arg value="client.ks"/>
    <constructor-arg value="client.truststore.ks"/>
    <constructor-arg value="secret"/>
    <constructor-arg value="secret"/>
</bean>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="clientConnectionFactory"
                           type="client"
                           host="localhost"
                           port="1234"
                           ssl-context-support="sslContextSupport" />
```

the recived error is:

```
Cannot resolve required base class 'org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.support.TcpSSLContextSupport'
```

As i understood from **sslContextSupport** class there are not any conflicts between this and **DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport** class.

**update**

After running the code these errors are generated

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientConnectionFactory': Invalid TcpSSLContextSupport - it failed to provide an SSLContext
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.last.webApp.webApp.WebAppApplication.main(WebAppApplication.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid TcpSSLContextSupport - it failed to provide an SSLContext
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport.<init>(DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport.java:46) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.config.TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.obtainSocketFactorySupport(TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.java:251) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.config.TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.createInstance(TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.java:196) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.config.TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.createInstance(TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.java:62) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:142) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [client.ks] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:211) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport.getSSLContext(DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport.java:107) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport.<init>(DefaultTcpNetSSLSocketFactorySupport.java:43) ~[spring-integration-ip-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    ... 22 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

also about my dependencies and versions

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent> 


<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace, as well as information on which version you are using.

Comment: Ok, i updated the question. I thinks that versions are the latest are not?

Comment: `class path resource [client.ks] cannot be opened because it does not exist`.

Comment: Yes i saw that.Unfortunatly i didnt manage to fine any proper description in document for these files so i asked this question

Comment: "Localhost" let's asume that you are in charge of the end point....google "create ssl (client+server) certificates" ..otherwise, they must be "handed" to you

Comment: I think still its not the case, i am not quite sure about creating these files beacuse also i have to provide similar files for server config. I think main problem is ralated to this error        
 **Cannot resolve required base class 'org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.support.TcpSSLContextSupport' 
**

Comment: But that is not what the stack trace indicates.

Comment: Before running the application first message is generated by IDE                                                                                        { Cannot resolve required base class 'org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.support.TcpSSLContextSupport'  }
and after running compiler generates other errors